# Lecture notes on holomorphic Yang-Mills theory

Tags: reference-request, mathematical-physics, complex-geometry, gauge-theory, connections

Some time ago I've found [these](http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/) lecture notes on the gauge theory. In particular, in these lecture notes the author introduces and studies the Yang-Mills equations in the case of real bundles and without using a lot of abstract algebra. Some time later I've faced with [this](http://verbit.ru/MATH/TALKS/Twistor-IPMU.pdf) presentation where results concerning the Yang-Mills theory in the case of holomorphic bundles are used. Unfortunately, I haven't found any lecture notes online or a book where this theory is described in details for the holomorphic case. Please, help me with references.